# Getting the fully qualified function name with parameters from FunctionDecl object in LLVM Clang

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

code example:

```
struct Foo {
int foo(int x) {
    return 1;
}
};
```

how can i get `int Foo::foo(int)` from FunctionDecl obj?

i call `FD->getQualifiedNameAsString()` only get `Foo::foo`

how can i get `int Foo::foo(int)` from FunctionDecl obj?

clang/llvm-14.0.0

Comment: Welcome to SO. C and C++ are very different languages. In C there is no such thing as `Foo::foo`. Please only add tags that are actually related to your question.